# List of command-line options?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Where is GTA 5's commandline.txt?

I've heard people talking about FPS counters, benchmark tests, etc; where can I find the list of commands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Commandline parameters can be added to the "commandline.txt" file in the root of the game folder. If this file doesn't exist, you can create it by right clicking in the game install directory, select New and select Text Document. Rename this file to commandline.txt. Please see below for the various command lines that can be used:

All GTA V PC Command Lines

```
-UseAutoSettings:
Use automatic generated settings

-benchmark:
Starts the benchmark test from the command line

-benchmarkFrameTimes:
Optionally output the individual frame times from the benchmark

-benchmarkIterations:
Specifies the number of iterations to run the benchmark for

-benchmarkPass:
Specifies an individual benchmark scene test should be done, and which test that should be

-benchmarknoaudio:
Disable audio processing for graphics benchmark purposes

-disableHyperthreading:
Don't count hyperthreaded cores as real ones to create tasks on

-goStraightToMP:
Jump straight to MP while loading

-ignoreDifferentVideoCard:
Don't reset settings with a new card

-ignoreprofile:
Ignore the current profile settings

-mouseexclusive:
Game uses mouse exclusively.

-noInGameDOF:
Disable In-game DOF effects

-safemode:
Start settings at minimum but don't save it

-shadowSoftness:
Selects between linear, rpdb, box 4x4, soft 16

-uilanguage:
Set language game uses

-useMinimumSettings:
Reset settings to the minimum

-HDStreamingInFlight:
Enable HD streaming while in flight

-SSA:
Enable SSA

-SSAO:
Set SSAO quality (0-2)

-anisotropicQualityLevel:
Set anisotropic Filter Quality Level (0-16)

-cityDensity:
Control city density (0.0 - 1.0)

-fogVolumes:
Enable lights volumetric effects in foggy weather

-fxaa:
Set FXAA quality (0-3)

-grassQuality:
Set grass quality (0-5)

-lodScale:
Set LOD Distance Level (0.0-1.0f)

-particleQuality:
Set particle quality (0-2)

-particleShadows:
Enable particle shadows

-pedLodBias:
Set Pedestrians LOD Distance Bias (0.0-1.0f)

-postFX:
Set postFX quality (0-3)

-reflectionBlur:
Enable reflection map blur

-reflectionQuality:
Set reflection quality (0-3)

-shaderQuality:
Set shader quality (0-2)

-shadowLongShadows:
Enable shadow rendering for dusk and dawn

-shadowQuality:
Set shadow quality (0-3)

-tessellation:
Set tessellation on or off (0-3)

-textureQuality:
Set texture quality (0-2)

-txaa:
Enable NVidia TXAA

-vehicleLodBias:
Set Vehicles LOD Distance Bias (0.0-1.0f)

-waterQuality:
Set water quality (0-1)

-keyboardLocal:
Sets the keyboard layout to the specified region.

-hdr:
Set the whole rendering pipeline to 16-bit

-noquattransform:
Don't use quaternion transforms for placed entities

-DX10:
Force 10.0 feature set

-DX10_1:
Force 10.1 feature set

-DX11:
Force 11.0 feature set

-GPUCount:
Manual override GPU Count

-adapter:
Use the specified screen adapter number (zero-based)

-borderless:
Set main window to be borderless

-disallowResizeWindow:
Do Not allow the window to be resized

-frameLimit:
number of vertical synchronizations to limit game to

-fullscreen:
Force fullscreen mode

-height:
Set height of main render window (default is 480)

-multiSample:
Number of multisamples (1, 2, 4, 8, or 16)

-width:
Set width of main render window (default is 640)

-windowed:
Force windowed mode

-StraightIntoFreemode:

If present the game will automatically launch into the multiplayer game in freemode.
```

[Reference](http://www.gamepur.com/guide/18581-full-list-gta-v-pc-command-lines-description-gta-v-pc-default-controls.html)

Comment: `-mouseexclusive` ... I doubt anybody will use that with these horrible airplane controls.